# KendoUI Numeric box doesn't set ngModel correctly

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-ngmodel, kendonumerictextbox

If I initialize input box which has ngModel attached to it like this:

```
angular.element(element.find("input")).kendoNumericTextBox({
  decimals : 4,
  format : "#.####"), // to match step and format
  step : step,
  value : value,
  min : scope.min,
  max : scope.max
});
```

Now, I enter value:

3.33333333

in it and it gets displayed:

3.3333

but ngModel is still set to 3.33333333

Is this a Kendo-AngularJS bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this as workaround (I have a scope variable model : "=ngModel"):

```
scope.$watch("model", function(newValue, oldValue) {
 if (newValue !== undefined) {
   kendoNumericBox.data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(newValue);
   scope.model = kendoNumericBox.data("kendoNumericTextBox").value()
 }
});
```

While saying this, there is also an issue if you update ngModel from controller it doesn't reflect in input until you click in it so I also did:

```
 scope.model = kendoNumericBox.data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
```

to retrieve value back again so it's validated with kendoNumericTextBox.

where kendoNumericBox is return value of kendoNumericTextBox constructor:

```
kendoNumericBox = elemenet.kendoNumericTextBox({. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is valid behavior. I reported issue to kendo-labs:

https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/issues/240#issuecomment-37793471